# Deploying a Windows Service along with the Windows Store app installation

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am planning to create a performance tune-up application for Windows 8 and would like to distribute it through the Windows Store.

Do Windows 8 applications (Metro apps) allows me to install a windows service onto the clients' system when he downloads my application through a Windows Store interface?

My idea was to have a service that does a constant tune-up and use Metro UI to control the service settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they do not allow you to install Services, unfortunately (well, kind-of fortunately, as that would be a large security risk). The Metro environment is a sandbox that allows data in and out only through specific guard systems and with specific, requested capabilities.

You may be able to have them install the service separately, but I'm not sure you'd be able to communicate with it or sell an app which does so on the store.

If you have your service hooked up to a WCF service or sending messages through Azure, then you could talk to it that way, but that'd be kind of roundabout.

Sorry I couldn't help you more, good luck.